# Yarn app timeout and no error

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, hadoop-yarn

I am running a map-reduce job triggered by YARN's REST API. The yarn app starts, triggers another map-reduce job. But the actual yarn app timeout exactly around 12 mins.

This is the final log where it ends:

```
2016-09-01 13:22:53 DEBUG ProtobufRpcEngine:221 - Call: getJobReport took 0ms
2016-09-01 13:22:54 DEBUG Client:97 - stopping client from cache: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client@6bbe2511
```

There are literally no errors or exceptions. I don't know which setting in Hadoop is causing this. 
The Diagnostics says `Application *application_whatever* failed 1 times due to ApplicationMaster for attempt *appattempt_application_whatever* timed out. Failing the application.`